# Django + PyMSQL + WSGI

Tags: python, mysql, django, mod-wsgi, pymysql

I have an application accessing a distant mysql base using PySQL and the following fonction

```
def db_query(username, password, host, db, query):
    try:
        db = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=username, passwd=password, db=db)
    except pymysql.err.OperationalError as e:
        errorLog = e
        return [0, errorLog]

    # you must create a Cursor object. It will let you execute all the query you need
    cur = db.cursor()

    cur.execute(query)
    result = cur.fetchall()

    cur.close()
    db.close()  

    return result
```

I have recently update Django from 1.7.1 to 1.7.3. Before update code worked. Now, when I'm in production using WSGI and only then (not on local dev server, nor on server dev server) I get a (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on [server.address] ([Errno 13] Permission denied)")

I have updated pymysql to latest version available on pip.

I see that 1.7.3 correcting some security issue in WSGI, i tried to downgrade to 1.7.2 (only by doing pip install django==1.7.2 (not sure this is the good way)) and the issue is still present.

Any idea on what i could try to check ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I think this is related to apache permission to access MySQL database. Can you try command: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`

Comment: Amazing, that's it ! It's working again. Actually the server rebooted just before it wouldn't work again, so i guess this setting was volatile. How can I set it to reboot ?

Comment: Using -P option makes the change persistent. Without this option, the boolean would be reset to 0 at reboot. Are you sure you executed the command with -P option?

Comment: Thank to you, now I did. I guess it didn't do it the first time. Thank a lot. You may want to publish the comment as an answer so i can accept it ?

Comment: Posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to apache permission to access MySQL database. Can you try command:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Using -P option makes the change persistent. Without this option, the boolean value would be reset to 0 at reboot.